# 11 GB of GPU RAM used, and no process listed by nvidia-smi

Tags: memory, nvidia, gpu

In my GPU #0, 11341MiB of GPU RAM is used, and no process is listed by `nvidia-smi`. How is that possible, and how can I get my memory back?

```
Thu Aug 18 14:27:58 2016
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.63     Driver Version: 352.63         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   61C    P2    71W / 250W |  11341MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   42C    P0    71W / 250W |     23MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:82:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   35C    P0    69W / 250W |     23MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P0    60W / 250W |     23MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I had launched a Theano Python script with a `lib.cnmem=0.9` flag, which explains why it used 11341MiB of GPU memory (the [CNMeM library](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cnmem) is a "simple library to help the Deep Learning frameworks manage CUDA memory.".). However, I killed the script, and was expecting the GPU memory to get released.

- `pkill -9 python` and `sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i 0` did not help.
- `sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*` didn't show any unwanted process.

I use a GeForce GTX Titan Maxwell with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64.

Comment: [Does this flushing][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197286/how-can-i-flush-gpu-memory-using-cuda-physical-reset-is-unavailable] out RAM from cuda works

Comment: The memory did not get released because you used SIGKILL(9). The SIGKILL signal forces the process to stop executing immediately. The program cannot ignore this signal. This process does not get to clean-up either. Always use SIGTERM(15) and if that doesn't work use SIGKILL as the last resource.

Comment: In other places on the Internet it looks like `nvidia-smi` may just not show all relevant processes. See e.g. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-doesnt-free-gpus-memory-of-it-gets-aborted-due-to-out-of-memory-error/13775 and https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/11-gb-of-gpu-ram-used-and-no-process-listed-by-nvidia-smi/44459/18 -- from these threads it seems that when you really kill every process that uses the device then memory will appear as free. I think "memory did not get released because you used SIGKILL" may be wrong. Maybe "don't trust nvidia-smi output"? :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `kill -9` for arbitrarily ending processes is a REALLY bad idea, and could mess things up. `SIGKILL` or signal 9 stops the process from executing immediately, without letting it finish anything and terminate properly. In this case when your script was killed, it probably didn't free up the RAM. In your case, the only way to reclaim the memory would be to reset the GPU via `nvidia-smi --gpu-reset` or, if not available, reboot.

Next time you need to simply stop a program, use kill without args which sends a `SIGTERM`, `SIGTERM` being a more friendly signal that allows the program to actually handle it and terminate. `SIGKILL` should be used only for stopping jobs not responding to other signals, and is a last resort.